# How do I link a thumbnail image to its content programatically?

Tags: media

I have the following php code in a rule. It displays a picture that was uploaded by a user.

How do I link the thumbnail to the content?

```
$imgpath = file_load(($node->field_image['und'][0]['fid']))->uri;
print theme_image_style(array( 'path' => $imgpath, 'style_name' => 'thumbnail'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this...

```
$imgpath = file_load(($node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid']))->uri;
$image = theme('image_style', array('path' => $imgpath, 'style_name' => 'thumbnail'));

$link = l($image, "node/$node->nid", array('html' => TRUE));
print $link;
```

Comment: Yes, that works well, thank you. It displays the link to the picture but not the picture. What I am trying to get, however, is the picture displayed in a thumbnail and when one hovers over it, the cursor changes to a hand. Clicking on it will take the viewer to the content. Or is that too complex?

Comment: It only print the link not the image and the downvote from me, please change it if you can and OP asked the same question here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/103578/displaying-thumbnail-image-linked-to-its-content

Comment: Sorry, silly typo - it should work now. Thanks @Bala

Comment: @user14666 The image should come out with the edited code, and the cursor should be a pointer by default - if not use `cursor: pointer` in css to do it

Comment: Yes, it's working now. Thank you so much. :) (And no need to add the css.)